# How to use splunk eval to show a list from an object property

Tags: splunk

I have a field called group in splunk which is an object like

```
group = { name: "bla", age: 20 }
```

I want to be able to display this as a list or if not as a string in my stats.

I tries using the obvious.

```
stats values(group) as status by ....
```

I'm able to drill down using group.name but I don't want name to show in the stats if its null.

Any ideas how I might go about this.

Answer (score 0):

presuming your sample `stats` line *works*, add this `where` clause after the `stats`:

```
| where isnotnull(status)
```